# I'm losing my hope for my Superuser t-shirt

Tags: support, t-shirt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where in the world is my SuperUser t-shirt?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49539/where-in-the-world-is-my-superuser-t-shirt)

My hope for getting my Superuser t-shirt began with the form I filled on **April 8th**, 2010. Then on **May 11th**, I asked [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49539/where-in-the-world-is-my-superuser-t-shirt) question. Jeff told me in his [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49539/where-in-the-world-is-my-superuser-t-shirt/49540#49540) that the t-shirts are on their way as of **June 4th**. Now it's **July 20th**, and I almost lost my hope after a long waiting period, namely 3½ months...

Will I ever receive my Superuser t-shirt in the near future?

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: This is pretty explanatory, thank you.

Comment: @Meh: You're always welcome! :)

Comment: You'll get it in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Prefer editing your original question rather than making a new one on the same topic. Especially if the update is only "still don't have it". On a side note, I received mine about a month ago (France).

Comment: I received mine 3 weeks ago (Romania).

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar: All t-shirts have been shipped. I contacted you via email to make sure you get your t-shirt. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: How can I get a T-shirt too?

Comment: Still waiting for my t-shirt too (Belgium) ... :-/

Comment: @Robert Cartaino - Don't mean to be pushy, but as others have said they have received them and you have said that they have been shipped, I am a little worried :( - Is there any sort of tracking number or are you sure mine has gone out?

Comment: @Robert Cartaino : I still did not get my tshirt. I guess it's not normal and it has been lost somewhere :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't look a gift horse in the mouth!

I wouldn't mind my one either, but free is free and I am sure when they are printed / ready, we will receive them!

(I got an email a short while ago saying about problems and that they will be despatched soon).

Comment: Wow, clicked Meta tag at the top and didn't realise I wasn't on meta.stackoverflow.com until I saw the reputation and though WTF!... @Jeff / team, nice and very good update!

Comment: Got mine in the mail around 3 weeks ago, so don't get your hopes up. They're probably preparing another batch.

Comment: @Wil / John T - I haven't got that mail

Comment: There has to be a difference between users doesn't there @Sathya ;-)

Comment: @Ivo Flipse - ? :S

Comment: Well I and John got one, so apparently they did manage to ship some @Wil. I was just being a **** about it ;-)

Comment: Do not look a gift horse in the butt, either.

Comment: I think the next batch of T-shirts will be sent and received by those on the front page before we poor folks can get the T-shirts.

Comment: @IvoFlipse +1, ahhh, ok, I thought you were making some sort of reference to Sathya having two users or something and was getting a bit confused! I don't get sarcasm that well!

Comment: I just received my t-shirt today. Special thanks to Jeff, Robert, and Emily.